# What is the best practice in terms of Bank Acount Primary Key. AccountNo or AccountID?

Tags: database, database-design, language-agnostic, data-modeling, entity-relationship

In many Bank Account applications' implementation, Account Number is always set as Primary Key. I was thinking what if the customer who is the account holder decides to move to a different Bank and he is given a new Account Number. Now the previous Bank decides to delete the customer account because there was no activities for a long period of time.

If the Bank used the customers' account numbers as Primary Keys. Now each and every Primary Key is seeded as 1 and it's incremented by 1 in order to be indexed. In this case where account number is set as Primary Key. What will happen when 100 customers leave the Bank to a different banks. The account numbers will be kept in the banking system or deleted?

If the Bank decides to keep the account numbers, how can this be possible for the reusability of an account number in the Banking System? If the Bank decides to delete the account number. Will not this affect Banking Record Order in terms of indexing and transaction history?

I need to understand this concept a little bit better in terms of using Account Number as Primary or Account ID as Primary Key. What is the best practice?

Comment: Well, one is called a "natural" primary key and the other a "surrogate" primary key. For list of advantages/disadvantages of one over the other, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key. In a nutshell, there are good arguments for both, and it depends on your specific use case as well as, to a certain degree, being a matter of taste.

Comment: 99% of the time I would advise to avoid natural keys. Their values always end up changing. Think of the ID card (the SSN): at first you may think it doesn't change... but it does under some circumstances you weren't able to see at first. Use a surrogate/synthetic key and sleep well at night.

Comment: "...previous Bank decides to delete the customer account..." - no institution will delete an account. The account will be marked as "closed" but won't be deleted for legal reasons, auditing, reporting, statistics, marketing, etc.

Comment: "...Now each and every Primary Key is seeded as 1 and it's incremented by 1..."  -- this is a common misconception. No one really cares about the values of the PKs; the key feature is that they are unique. Period.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I didn't even know that bank accounts are not deleted but only closed for legal reasons. Thanks for this light.

Comment: Not only do they not reuse account numbers, they use large enough numbers for account numbers that they have tens of millions available and will generally have intentional gaps between account numbers.  Most credit cards use 12 digits for the account number. 999,999,999,999 possible accounts.  They don't need to reuse the numbers. 
 A single credit card institution has a large enough range to issue 100+ cards to every person on earth.

Comment: Wow, this is interesting.

Comment: Typically when you run out of IDs you archive the old data into another system and then start filling holes by turning off autonumbering. Which does happen in various circumstances where the original design was never expected to overflow such as: UPNs, work order IDs, requisition IDs, purchase order numbers, sales order numbers, ... However doing this is quite annoying and costly, so if you find your self in such a situation it may be a whole lot cheaper to go with a system redesign and port the active data from the old system to the new.